# unified_thread still not open for public?

Tags: facebook, messaging, facebook-fql

According to Facebook they released their new messaging system way back,
http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/591/

From the Blog:

> Apps should move to the new messaging Graph API endpoints and messaging FQL tables ('unified_message' and 'unified_thread'). We will be formally deprecating the old messaging REST APIs, Graph APIs and messaging FQL tables at a date to be announced in the future.

But I still getting the "must be a developer". Is this just me, or does this work for anyone?

I'll try to use unified_thread table from FQL.
Facebook suggests to move to that table, but it's still not working after 6 months?

Comment: Still not available? `(#298) You must be a developer of the application` using the Graph API Explorer app.

Answer (score 0):

What method are you using to query the FQL?  I am able to query this table without issue using the PHP SDK and making a graph call to /fql?q=query

Comment: e.g SELECT snippet FROM unified_thread WHERE has_tags('inbox'). If I use my own apps access_token it works fine, but if I try e.g ith Graph explorer access_token I get: {
  "error": {
    "message": "(#298) You must be a developer of the application",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 298
  }
}

Comment: Any news on that? I'm even believing now that it doesn't work with the Graph Explorer only?!