# Is there a way to get the ID of a message thread in Facebook?

Tags: facebook, parsing, url, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

If I have the URL of a facebook thread from a user's messages, is there a way to get the id of that thread? I get how to construct a url given an id, but not the other way around.

The URL can have two formats:

`https://www.facebook.com/messages/123456789`
or 
`https://www.facebook.com/messages/<username>`

I need to be able to handle both cases.

Thanks.

Comment: The question is plenty clear. Can someone explain to me what they don't understand instead of downvoting?

Comment: In fact, is the question as simple to explain as "How to get a thread ID from a user ID/username"?

Comment: Sure, that's a simpler way of looking at it. I put it down the way I did in case people were aware of edge cases with the URL that they knew how to handle. URL's tend to be finnicky to work with sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT thread_fbid 
  FROM unified_thread 
 WHERE single_recipient = <USER ID>
```

*Doc:* https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/unified_thread

This gives exactly what you want. The problem is:

```
(#298) You must be a developer of the application
```

Please read [unified_thread still not open for public?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11470158/unified-thread-still-not-open-for-public)

---

So, one actual **workaround** would be to loop on all the threads from `graph.facebook.com/me/inbox?fields=to` as long as you didn't find one which:

- has only 2 participants (because some threads are group conversations and you don't want them),
- **and** contains the participant who is the person represented by a user ID/username.

This has to be done manually, using your favorite language.

Comment: Yes, I do know how to get that, but the problem is that often the url is in this format: `https://www.facebook.com/messages/<username>` I'm having trouble handling that case.

Comment: You never spoke about any `username` in your question. Please make the question clear!

Comment: I don't see the single_recipient field in the unified_message documentation? Is that implied somehow?

Comment: Oops, wrong link. Corrected to `unified_thread`.

Comment: The fql is no longer available.